# Error: sanitazer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular15

I coded the follow unit test. It is quite easy but I receive continually the error: `TypeError: this.sanitazer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle is not a function` and I can´t figure it out. Would you mind to take a look?

```
it('should sanitize the style and return SafeStyle', () => {
      let sanitizer: DomSanitizer = TestBed.inject(DomSanitizer);

      const imageName = 'your-image.jpg';
      const props = 'width: 100%; height: auto;';
      const expectedSafeStyle: SafeStyle = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${component.baseImgPath}${imageName}) ${props}`);
  
      const safeStyle = component.sanitizeStyle(imageName, props);
  
      expect(safeStyle).toEqual(expectedSafeStyle);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem. To make sure that both component and test use the same sanitizer I finally chose to inject it into a function that I created to emulate the behavior of the component.

```
it('should sanitize the style with default props', () => {
      const imageName = 'image.jpg';
      const baseImgPath = 'path/';
      const expectedSafeStyle: SafeStyle = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${baseImgPath + imageName}) `);
  
      const result = sanitizeStyle(imageName, undefined, sanitizer, baseImgPath);

    expect(result).toEqual(expectedSafeStyle);
    });

function sanitizeStyle(imageName: string, props: string = '', sanitizer: DomSanitizer, baseImgPath: string): SafeStyle {
  let url = baseImgPath + imageName;
  return sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${url}) ${props}`);
}
```